# Which plane is most loaded in relation to it's capacity?

Tags: java

i  have to found out the plane that is most loaded in relation to it's capacity.

I create a formula inside my Plane class :

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Plane {
    private String name;
    private int sitPLaces;
    private int capacity;

    List<Passanger> passangers = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Baggage> baggage = new ArrayList<>();

    public Plane(String name, int sitPLaces, int capacity) {
        this.name = name;
        this.sitPLaces = sitPLaces;
        this.capacity = capacity;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getSitPLaces() {
        return sitPLaces;
    }

    public void setSitPLaces(int sitPLaces) {
        this.sitPLaces = sitPLaces;
    }

    public int getCapacity() {
        return capacity;
    }

    public void setCapacity(int capacity) {
        this.capacity = capacity;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Plane{" +
                "name='" + name + '\'' +
                ", sitPLaces=" + sitPLaces +
                ", capacity=" + capacity +
                '}';
    }

    public void addPassanger(Passanger newPassanger) {
        if (capacity < passangers.size()) {
            // System.out.println("No space for more passangers");
        } else {
            // System.out.println("Welcome to board!");
        }
        passangers.add(newPassanger);
    }

    //todo you need sum of weight baggages and passengers to compare it
    public void addBaggage(Baggage newBaggage) {
        baggage.add(newBaggage);
    }

    public int getKgPassanger() {
        int totalKg = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < passangers.size(); i++) {
            totalKg += passangers.get(i).getWeight();
        }
        return totalKg;
    }

    public int getKgBaggage() {
        int totalKg = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < baggage.size(); i++) {
            totalKg += baggage.get(i).getWeigh();
        }
        return totalKg;
    }
    public int getCombinedKg(){
        return getKgBaggage() + getKgPassanger();
    }


    public int getHowManyPassangersAreIn() {
        return passangers.size();

    }

}
```

That helps me to get the sum of Passangers Kg and Baggages Kg -  now i know i have to compare the sum of those  with the  Capacity  and return the  most laoded to it's capacity (in my situation
should be Plane  ({"Plane plane2 = new Plane("Flig", 200, 2000)"})

Here is my Main class:

```
import java.util.List;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
Plane plane1 = new Plane("Beoing", 350, 3000);
        plane1.addPassanger(new Passanger("Victor", 100));
        plane1.addPassanger(new Passanger("Stefan", 100));


        plane1.addBaggage(new Baggage("Kipling", 100));
        plane1.addBaggage(new Baggage("Kipling", 100));

        Plane plane2 = new Plane("Flig", 200, 2000);
        plane2.addPassanger(new Passanger("Mihai", 100));
        plane2.addPassanger(new Passanger("Rudy", 100));
        plane2.addPassanger(new Passanger("Rudy", 100));

        plane2.addBaggage(new Baggage("Kipling", 100));
        plane2.addBaggage(new Baggage("Kipling", 100));
        plane2.addBaggage(new Baggage("Kipling", 100));


        Plane plane3 = new Plane("Aly", 400, 2500);
        plane3.addPassanger(new Passanger("Vlad", 100));
        plane3.addPassanger(new Passanger("Vali", 100));
        plane3.addPassanger(new Passanger("Ionut", 100));
        plane3.addPassanger(new Passanger("Ionut", 100));

        plane3.addBaggage(new Baggage("Kipling", 100));
        plane3.addBaggage(new Baggage("Kipling", 100));
        plane3.addBaggage(new Baggage("Kipling", 100));
        plane3.addBaggage(new Baggage("Kipling", 100));


        List<Plane> planeList = List.of(plane1, plane2, plane3);

Plane mostLoadedinRelation = getMostLoadedinRelation(planeList);
        System.out.println("This plane its loaded most in relation to it's capacity: " + mostLoadedinRelation);
}
```

I made an for() but i do not get the result i need, and i assume that here i am not comparing the right things .

```
  public static Plane getMostLoadedinRelation(List<Plane> planeList) {
    Plane closest = planeList.get(0);

    for (int i = 0; i < planeList.size(); ++i) {
        if (planeList.get(i).getCombinedKg() < planeList.get(i).getCapacity()) {
            closest = planeList.get(i);
        }
    }
    return closest;
}
```

Is it possible to help me by giving me a hint ?
Thanks,

Comment: The question asks for "most loaded in relation to it's capacity", but I do not see you using the capacity anywhere. Also, in your for-loop you're choosing the plane with the least combined kg, not the most.

Comment: So what does the `capacity` parameter limit: the number of passenger seats, or the maximal weight of the passengers and baggage?

Comment: What does most loaded in relation to it's capacity mean? Maybe it is a ratio like seats taken / seats available?

Comment: @AlexRudenko , i need to  comapare the  maximal weight of passangers and baggage   to  thae capacity of the plane   not the seats .

Comment: @JoeChris   the relation is : the  closest  combined Kg to the Capacity of plane ,  so in the example above it's plane2 since the combined Kg is  the most close to the capacity of the plane

Comment: @PetrJaneček  Sorry i  saw  it now that i  head  wrong comparation , now it's edited

Comment: `plane3` seems to be most loaded: 800/2500 (32%) > 600/2000 (30%)

Comment: if maximal weight compared with capacity, then method `addPassengers` is incorrect -- here the capacity in `kg` is compared to the number of passenger seats.

Comment: @AlexRudenko , For   "plane3 seems to be most loaded: 800/2500 (32%) > 600/2000 (30%)"    i need to  =  2500-800 = 1700  and  2000-600=1400  in this case  mose loade to it's capacity it's  2000-600  since  1400 i clsoest to the capacity200  then  1700 to 2500

Comment: @AlexRudenko ,  in method `addPassangers` i compare the Capacity to the passanger.size if i understood good your point.

Comment: Then you look for the absolute minimum of free weight (capacity - totalWeight), for instance, there could be a smaller plane with capacity 1600 and 400 kg used -- its load rate is just 25%, but its free weight is just 1200 kg.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241047/discussion-between-becalinr1-and-alex-rudenko).

Comment: @AlexRudenko   , 
So you mean that i can use in my if() capacity - totalWeight ? if yes , with what i should compare it then ?

Comment: Worked perfectly  @AlexRudenko  
`planeList.get(i).getCapacity() - planeList.get(i).getCombinedKg() <= loadedInCapacity.getCombinedKg()`